# Is there a difference between writing to a btrfs snapshot or to its original?

Tags: btrfs

After creating a btrfs subvolume produces two directories (one representing the subvolume, the other the writable snapshot). When writing to one of them, the changes are not reflected in the other, so is there any other difference to pay attention to. If yes, where to write to (the snapshot or the original)? I'm using Linux 3.19.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as btrfs is concerned, the writable snapshot is just a regular subvolume. The only special relationship the writable snapshot has with its parent subvolume is that it starts with identical contents and changes are handled in a copy-on-write way.

So the answer is that you can use the writable snapshot however you want to. It's just another subvolume that happens to share underlying data blocks with the original.